# How to configure dynamic Subdomains for SaaS Product using wildcard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, cname, wildcard-subdomain

My website URL is `www.example.com`. Whenever any user signup i want to offer them dynamic url based on their name. For eg -

For ClientA - url should be - `http://clientA.example.com`
For ClientB - url should be - `http://clientB.example.com`
For ClientC - url should be - `http://clientC.example.com` ...and so on...

How can I accomplish this? I am hosting my app on Amazon aws and registered domain onn Godaddy. So I tried following -

Changed Apache httpd.conf file on AWS with -

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName     www.example.com
    ServerAlias    example.com
    ServerAdmin    webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot   /var/www/html/web-site/
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName     app.example.com
    ServerAlias    *.example.com
    ServerAdmin    webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot   /var/www/html/myapp/
</virtualhost>
```

And then changed CNAME settings on GoDaddy -

Host: '*' 
Point to : '@'

The above httpd.cnf is giving warning when I was trying to restart apache - 
`[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence` (However it restarted with status 'OK')

Now when I am opening `www.clientA.example.com`, Page correspond to `/var/www/html/web-site/` get loaded instead of `'/var/www/html/myapp/'`

I was wondering if my approach is not correct or am I missing something?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. I was missing just one simple thing -

I had to add NameVirtualHost in my httpd.conf file as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```